# Overwrite item copied based on title

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have two lists, and I have a workflow that copies one item from one list to the second on a field change.
Sometimes, one item can be copied even if it has already been.
I would like to overwrite this item in the second list but I can't with the advanced property of workflow because the id in the two lists isn't the same.

**So how can I overwrite an item with the same title, not ID?**

OR

**How can I keep the same ID of an element in a first list and in the second where it has been copied?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've found a solution. It's a tricky one, but it works.
You can do that with Designer in your workflow.

**What you have to do is:**

1. Test **if** a field of your element of list A **is different than** the same field of the element of list B (e.g Title field - maybe it doesn't exist yet, that's why it's tricky),
2. Do your stuff if it's true, if it's not, do nothing or continue the workflow.

It works for me, I hope for you too.

Comment: Perfect!! thx guy

Comment: Happy to read this ! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we have SPD workflow which triggers on item update. The workflow perform below actions;

1. Delete the item from second list with same title
2. Then copy the item from first list to second list.

This way we keep the latest copy of item of first list to the second list